# need to block direct access xml using htaccess still need to access through kodi app

Tags: .htaccess, kodi

i have lot of xml files on my server i need to block direct access of xml file like if someone copy xml url and need to redirect somewhere but i need to access that xml through kodi app. i got success to direct access of xml but that blocking kodi access also. please check below code is my htaccess which blocks direct access.

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://newdomainexample.com/
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(xml)$ - [F]
```

above htaccess also blocking htaccess from kodi. i need kodi can access url but people cant access directly.

any solution please

Comment: you may use your custom headers and authentication token for veifying request

Comment: you mean i need to pass headers from kodi app when i send request right ?

Comment: yes and verify it on your server

Comment: ok is there not any way that we can do directly through htaccess on server ?

Comment: think your self as a server and then think how will you determine which request is to block and which to allow, you'll get your answer